# Запретить ввод с клавиатуры[Java]

Tags: java

Как в Java запретить ввод букв и использование пробела ?

Comment: Где именно? На каком UI?

Answer (score 2):

Можете использовать запрет на буквы и пробел, юзер сможет вводить только цифры:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
      if ( ((c < '0') || (c > '9'))) {
         e.consume();  // игнорим введенные буквы и пробел
      }
   }
});
```

Если вам нужны какие-нибудь символы, то их код вы можете найти на [странице Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) и дописать в `if`:

```
if ( ((c < '0') || (c > '9')) && (c != KeyEvent.VK_PLUS)) {
   e.consume();  // разрешаем цифры и знак "+"
}
```

Comment: А почему вы решили, что у автора не обычное консольное приложение?